# UDP server not receiving scapy packets

Tags: python, sockets, udp, wireshark, scapy

I have a very simple udp server that is as follows:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
srv.bind(('192.168.134.128',666)

while True:
        data, address = server.recvfrom(2048)
        print('Received from %s: %s' % (address, data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Using standard python socket examples i can successfully use a python socket to send data across to the server. I would then expect to be able to receive UDP packets crafted in scapy, however i am having no such luck. I have tried sending from both layer 2 and 3 using the following commands:

```
sendp(Ether()/IP(src='192.168.134.128',dst='192.168.134.128')/UDP(dport=666),iface='ens33')

send(IP(src='192.168.134.128',dst='192.168.134.128')/UDP(dport=666),iface='ens33')
```

I've looked at every answer on stack overflow concerning roughly this that i can find and so far nothing has helped me. This is the most up to date build of scapy running on an ubuntu 18.01 vm, with both scapy and the client running on the same machine. I can also see the packets generated by scapy on wireshark fine when sent using sendp, however when i do standard python client/server messaging i see nothing on wireshark, just in case that is also useful information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: With `src='192.168.134.128',dst='192.168.134.128'`, you're not sending the packet outside of your computer. Depending on the networking stack, you may not see sent/return traffic. As it looks like you are learning how to use Scapy, I would set up a separate VM as a client/server for this purpose.

Comment: Just tried the server code on my windows machine and the packets are received fine from that, but still doesn't work entirely within the VM. This is fine for my purposes, i suppose there's just some strangeness happening within the VM when i'm trying to have it send messages to itself. Thanks for the tip, i've been bashing my head against the wall all day and overlooked something this simple